# Spring Remoting - HTTP Invokers

Tags: java, spring, spring-remoting

What do you think of Spring's HTTP Invokers?

I'd like that two Tomcat servers exchange objects, exposed by a service, through HTTPS.
Do you think that Spring HTTP Invoker is a good choice?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Http invokers are wonderfully easy to use, and quick to get up and running. However, they suffer from the same major caveat that affects RMI, which is that your object serialization has to be carefully managed. If one end of the connection is running a different version of the code, it must be serialization compatible with the other end. This is a general "problem" with java serialization, and not specific to Spring remoting.

Answer (score 3):

If it is Java-to-Java, the [Http invoker](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.html) is the preferred choice, with least overhead.

> HTTP invoker is the recommended protocol for Java-to-Java remoting.  It is more powerful and more extensible than Hessian and Burlap, at the expense of being tied to Java. Nevertheless, it is as easy to set up as Hessian and Burlap, which is its main advantage compared to RMI.